# INSERT INTO database using a $_GET variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make a private message system where users can have conversations with each other. Each conversation has its unique hash. I want to store the messages in my database but for some reason the value of hash gets stored as 0 instead of the number I am requesting.

```
<form method="post" action="exiConversations.php" id="sendMessageFooterForm">
    <input type="text" name="userNewMessage" id="userMessage" placeholder="Type een bericht" />
    <input type="submit" name="sendNewMessageSubmit" id="sendMessageSubmit" value="Verzend" />
        <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['sendNewMessageSubmit'])) {
            $message = $_POST['userNewMessage'];
            $fromUser = $_SESSION['userID'];
            $today = date("y/m/d H:i:s");
            $exiHash = $_GET['hash'];
            $insertNewMessage = $conn->query("INSERT INTO messages (fromuser, messagedate, message, grouphash) VALUES ('$fromUser', '$today', '$message', '$exiHash')");
        }
        ?>
</form>
```

I dont know what to do anymore. It used var_dump($exiHash); which does show me the hash number I want to store but it only stores a 0.

Comment: which type the column `grouphash`?

Comment: @alexander.polomodov yes I want to store it in the colum grouphash

Comment: You really need to `escape` your variables before submitting to database. Especially since you are directly coming from user generated urls. Depending on what you're using as a framework, im unsure the right function, but would be something like $conn->real_escape_string($variable),  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Also for the 0, what is the database setup for on the `grouphash` column? Is it `int` ? If so you need to change it to `char` or `varchar`, my guess is it only allows integers.

Comment: From the code you have there, I don't see how `$_GET['hash']` would be set when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your action attr in form tag.
it must me like

```html
action="exiConversations.php?<?=$_GET['hash']?>"
```

but it will work only if you have current URL like ....?hash=45345345

Comment: *"but it will work only if you have current URL like ....?hash=45345345"* - Not entirely true. That could come from a pre-fetched db query.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Or from session variable. Or other POST variable (if this page loaded from form). Many variants :)